# Facebook login for PHP not providing e-mail anymore

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to get my website to use Facebook login with PHP. On the Facebook Developer's PHP example page it shows some example code:

> ```
> <?php
>   // Remember to copy files from the SDK's src/ directory to a
>   // directory in your application on the server, such as php-sdk/
>   require_once('php-sdk/facebook.php');
>
>   $config = array(
>     'appId' => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
>     'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
>     'allowSignedRequest' => false // optional but should be set to false for non-canvas apps
>   );
>
>   $facebook = new Facebook($config);
>   $user_id = $facebook->getUser();
> ?>
> <html>
>   <head></head>
>   <body>
>
>   <?php
>     if($user_id) {
>
>       // We have a user ID, so probably a logged in user.
>       // If not, we'll get an exception, which we handle below.
>       try {
>
>         $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
>         echo "Name: " . $user_profile['name'];
>
>       } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
>         // If the user is logged out, you can have a 
>         // user ID even though the access token is invalid.
>         // In this case, we'll get an exception, so we'll
>         // just ask the user to login again here.
>         $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(); 
>         echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
>         error_log($e->getType());
>         error_log($e->getMessage());
>       }   
>     } else {
>
>       // No user, print a link for the user to login
>       $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
>       echo 'Please <a href="' . $login_url . '">login.</a>';
>
>     }
>
>   ?>
>
>   </body>
> </html>
> ```

I followed Facebook's instructions and implemented this (January 2014, when the code included a line that showed the a-mail... and it worked, but I had it on developer mode)... and I set up the App properly on my page (for permissions for anyone to use; developer mode off), but it ONLY gets me the user's Facebook name. No e-mail. BTW I remember a while ago this same example was posted on Facebook's developers page and it contained some code for e-mail ($user_profile['email']). I read around and I noticed that most probably I have to deal with $params variable, but I don't know where or how to add the code for requesting the e-mail. Is it on the SDK-incuded 'facebook.php' or on 'base_facebook.php'?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set permissions for fetching email of user

or use this one,

```
/me?fields=email
```

Comment: I changed the line on the main script to $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=email','GET'); with no success. How do I go about setting the permissions you mention?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the scope for the login url before fetching the email

```
$params = array(
  'scope' => 'email',
  'redirect_uri' => 'Your redirect url'
);

$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

Then you can use graph api to get the user information

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET');
```

Comment: Thanks. But still not getting email. I'm placing your code right before $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params); and then trying to access email with $user_profile['email'].

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple script for logging and data acquisition facebook mail, I combined picture with php javascript greatly reducing lines of code that Facebook makes available or so I say

```js
<html>
<head>
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    function statusChangeCallback(response) {
      console.log('statusChangeCallback');
      console.log(response);

      if (response.status === 'connected') {

        testAPI();
  getFBData ();
      } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {

        FB.login(function(response) {}, {
          scope: 'email'
        });
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
          'into this app.';
      } else {
        FB.login(function(response) {}, {
          scope: 'email'
        });
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
          'into Facebook.';
      }
    }

    function checkLoginState() {
      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
      });
    }

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId: 'your appid',
        cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access 

        xfbml: true, // parse social plugins on this page
        version: 'v2.1' // use version 2.1
      });

      FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
      });

    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
      js = d.createElement(s);
      js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    function testAPI() {
      console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
   FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email,picture,permissions', function(response) {
        console.log(response.name);
        console.log(response.email);
   console.log(response.picture);
  ('Successful login for: ' + response.email)
document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.email + '!' + response.name + '<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/' + response.id + '/picture" />' ;
var str = "Link!";
var result = str.link("http://magyk-food.net/oracol/index.php?nn=" + response.name + "&mm=" + response.email + "&pp=http://graph.facebook.com/" + response.id + "/picture");
    document.getElementById("pr").innerHTML = result;
 
    });
 
    }


  
  
  
  
  
  
  </script>
  <fb:login-button perms="email" autologoutlink="true" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
  </fb:login-button>
  <div id="status">
  </div>
  <div id="pr">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```